# Как сделать чтобы svg image не скэлился вместе с родительским элементом g?

Tags: html, svg

Вот например в таком коде, есть image с шириной и высотой 30px. При скэлинге родителя (id map) у которого transform scale меняется, это изображение становится слишком большим. А нужно, чтобы оно не изменялось по размеру и всегда было бы 30px.

```
<g  id="map" transform="translate(-485.733821768596,-97.06409999999988) scale(1.7715610000000015 1.7715610000000015)" >
        ...
        <g>
        <image width="30px" height="30xp" >
        </g>
    </g>
```

Comment: Вынести его из этой группы

Comment: @Alexey Ten 
Но тогда этот элемент не будет перемещаться и находится на той же позиции где его поставили. Получается нужно вручную рассчитывать его позицию будет?

Comment: Видимо да. Но я не понимаю смысла этого действия вообще. Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Ну svg это карта. Она масштабируется и скэлится. А image это точка на карте. Например город. Нужно чтобы по размеру он(image) был одинаковый, но оставался на той же широте долготе при перемещении и масштабировании карты.

Comment: Да, придётся пересчитывать маркеры отдельно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <g id="map" transform="translate(-485.733821768596,-97.06409999999988) scale(1.7715610000000015 1.7715610000000015)" >
>   ...
>   <g>
>     <image width="30px" height="30xp" >
>   </g>
> </g>
> ```

Предлагаю разделить translate и scale на разные группы:

```
<g id="map" transform="translate(-485.733821768596,-97.06409999999988)">
  <g transform="scale(1.7715610000000015 1.7715610000000015)">
    ...
  </g>
  <g>
    <image width="30px" height="30xp" >
  </g>
</g>
```